# Angular 4 router first load route not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

**Import both**

```
import { ResetComponent } from './pass-recovery/reset.component'; 

import { HomeComponent } from './HomeComponent';
```

**Route Path**

```
{ path: 'reset/:id/:token', component: ResetComponent, data : {type : 'password'} },

{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }

// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
```

Problem is only occur on angular first load and after first load it is working fine.
When I route on "localhost:88/#/reset/12/tokenabc" then it do not route it and go to home page. May be it means it did not find route.

Comment: Can you try without `#` ?

Comment: Do you have a registered route to home? `{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried without #

Yes I have a registered route to home

Comment: Is the wildcard route specified last in the routes array ? Order of routes matters.

Comment: Please try to format your entry, It looks horrible.

Comment: Can you show the complete routing module?

Comment: **emkay** Sorry I can't show complete routing module

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that Problem is only occur on angular first load and after first load it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the data attribute and try to fetch

```
{ path: 'reset/:id/:token', component: ResetComponent}
```

Answer (score -1):

Show your [online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-router-question).

In app.module.ts

```
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test/:id/:token',
    component: TestComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/home'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In app.component.html

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```